# my jQuery.css does not work

Tags: jquery

I am using

```
$('div:first', $('#' + id)).css({ 'color': 'red' })
```

to change the color of my div,  but it does not work in my page.Then when I get the color by code

```
$('div:first', $('#' + id)).css('color')
```

,it is red! Who can tell me what happened?

I got the right answer about my problem, but it is deleted by someone. I paste it here and hope it can help others.

```
$('div:first', '[id="' + id + '"]').css({'color': 'red' });
```

And I will be very thankful if someone can tell me the difference between my code and the answer!

Comment: `$('div:first', $('#' + id)).css( 'color', 'red', 'important' );`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div:first', $('#' + id)).css( 'color', 'red' );
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is different than just passing JSON data to $.css?

Answer (score 0):

Try like `$('div:first', $('#' + id)).css('color')`

Comment: Sorry,it's my fault. I changed the question, and my problem is about set,not get...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace them with

```
$('div:first', $('#' + id)).css( 'color', 'red' );
```